# Active record store with nested hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Using the ActiveRecord::Store for serialization, the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html) give the following example implementation:

```
cass User < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :settings, accessors: [ :color, :name ], coder: JSON
end
```

And the results like this

> {"color"=>"red", "name"=>"abcde"}

My question is, if there is any way to get the output like this

> `first: {color: 'red', name: 'abcde'}, second: {color: 'pink', name: 'abcd'}`

like nested hashes.

Comment: If you are using a JSON/JSONB column on PG or MySQL you don't need to use `ActiveRecord::Store`. You only need it if you are using a string column as "ghetto JSON" in legacy apps.

Comment: And as to the other part of the question. No it does not create accessors for nested objects or arrays of objects. I would consider if you should be using a table and an association instead of JSON as the EAV anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks @max. I am using rails 6 with active admin. If I want succeed above result (first: {color: 'red', name: 'abcde'}, second: {color: 'pink', name: 'abcd'}) means, what i really want to do. Give me some suggestion.